# Blazor NavigationManager reset

Tags: navigation, blazor

I have a Blazor app in which I use NavigationManager. It highlights links in the side menu as menus are selected or I navigate to a URL. However, on some forms that are reached through one of the pages, I dont want the side menu to be highlighted. Meaning, I want the NavigationManager in the same state as I started the app and no `<NavLink>` was highlighted.

How do I achieve this in Blazor?

`NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/someurl");`

takes me to a URL. But I just want to reset my navigation state.

Comment: You can't "reset" navigation state.  `NavigationManager` interacts with the browser page to  get it's information.  `NavLink` injects `NavigationManager` and uses its reported Url to match its `href`, and thus decide whether to highlight or not.  It looks like you need to write your own version of `NavLink` control.

Comment: NavLink is just a wrapper for an Anchor that applies or removes a class on Navigation. Just use an anchor `<a ...`.
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Routing/NavLink.cs,4241885b84240c12